# How to react to changes in the dimension/size of a video track in a `MediaStream`?

Tags: javascript, mediastream

In my web app I obtain a `MediaStream` either via `getUserMedia` or `getDisplayMedia`. In certain situations, the video track of that stream can change its size. For example, if `getDisplayMedia` tracks a specific window, that window can change size. Or on a mobile device, when switching from landscape into portrait mode, the camera image will be rotated by 90° (i.e. width and height get swapped).

I know how to get the dimensions of the `MediaStream` ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076259/get-media-detailsresolution-and-frame-rate-from-mediastream-object/46602406#46602406)). I now want to get notified whenever the dimensions *change*. A callback/event of some sorts.

I already tried `MediaStream.onaddtrack` (guessing that maybe the track is removed and readded with a different size) and I also tried using a `MutationObserver` on the `<video>` element I am showing the stream in. None of these worked. I also checked MDN for other events that might help me, but I didn't find any promising ones.

**Is there a way to subscribe to changes of a video track's dimension?** A function of mine should be called each time the dimensions change. And if it's not possible and I would need to busy poll: is there a smart way how to make the polling a bit less busy?

Comment: If this is about a camera orientation, could you use the [orientationchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientationchange_event) event?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can subscribe to `resize` event of your video element

```
const video = document.getElementById("video");

video.addEventListener("resize", (e) => {
  const { videoWidth, videoHeight } = video;
  // can do smth here
  // for example
  video.style.width = videoWidth;
  video.style.height = videoHeight;

}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is a solution that does not require a `<video>` element, i.e. just works with a `MediaStream`?

Comment: It works the same as with video tag. **htmlVideoElement** has also `.videoHeight`property. 
You will end up with video element in any case. 
`const stream = new MediaStream();
const video = document.createElement('video');
video.srcObject = stream;`